# CMake - Compiler can't find public headers from another (target_link_labraries)

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to write a build script with modern CMake (no global variables and with targets). Everything went fine so far, but now I want to link a library (module2) to a library (module1) that depends on the first. But the public header of module2 is not found by the compiler but the include directory is listed in "build/CMakeFiles/Module1.dir/includes_CXX.rsp". So my question is, how I get this working?

Structure of the project:

```
|-Module1
|-|-inc (public headers)
|-|-src (private headers and sources)
|-|-CMakeLists.txt (3)
|-Module2
|-|-inc (here is "module2.h" which I want to include in Module1)
|-|-src
|-|-CMakeLists.txt (2)
|CMakeLists.txt (1)
```

Project-CMakeLists.txt (1): No executable at the moment

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(foo CXX)   
add_subdirectory(Module2)
add_subdirectory(Module1)
```

Module2-CMakeLists.txt (2):

```
add_library(Module2 OBJECT 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/module2_1.cpp 
)
target_include_directories(Module2 
    PUBLIC 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
    PRIVATE
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>      
)
```

Module1-CMakeLists.txt (3):

```
add_library(Module1 OBJECT   
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/add.cpp 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/sub.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/functions2mock.cpp
)

target_include_directories(Module1 
    PUBLIC 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
    PRIVATE
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>  
)
target_link_libraries(Module1 PRIVATE Module2)
```

I thought with the command "target_link_libraries" Module1 get all public includes, flags etc. from Module2.

I hope somebody can help me, thanks.

Greetings.

Comment: target_link_libraries has nothing to do with header files. Add include directories with target_include_directories.

Comment: What is the include directive you use in the cpp files of Module1? Is it `#include "module2.h"`.

Comment: @eddi, No your cmake files look correct. The include idrectory is in the public interface of Module2 target.

Comment: Yes. I include this with `#include "module2.h"`

Comment: Sorry. I found the error. I included another target that depends on this in a unit test module. I've overseen this. I worked on this for the last 4 hours and didn't see this. I think I have to go to bed now. But good to know that the cmake files are correct so far. Thanks for your time.